# DS1302 maximum current source/sink?

Tags: rtc, specifications

What is the recommended and maximum current sourcing and sinking capability on the DS1302?

Is this what's given by "Active Supply Current" in [the spec](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS1302.pdf)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current source and sink are given as IOL and IOH on the data sheet.
That is for signal pins. Not sure if that is what you are after.

Comment: I looked right past IOL and IOH. What I'm looking for is: the sinking capability of both the SCLK and CE pins as well as the source AND sinking capability of the IO pin. I'm trying to select reasonable isolating resistors.

Comment: You don't need resistors to limit current into the pins; it does it on its own.

Comment: Oops, you're right. But what about the I/O pin? I want to protect against programming error. I don't wanna write a low into a pin that's outputting high, or vice versa. (You already answered this: It's IOL and IOH). Thanks, dude!